# First boxplot missing or not visible

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, boxplot

**Why is the first boxplot missing?** There's supoussed to be 24 boxplots, but only 23 are being display as you can see in the image. **Who's size do i have to change to make it visible?** I've tried changing the size of the figure but its the same.

[image: Enero Boxplot is out of the square figure]

Not sure if it helps, but this is the code:

```
def obtenerBoxplotsAnualesIntercalados(self, directorioEntrada, directorioSalida):
    meses = ["Enero","Febrero","Marzo","Abril","Mayo","Junio", "Julio", "Agosto","Septie.","Octubre","Noviem.","Diciem."]
    ciudades = ["CO","CR"]      
    anios = ["2011", "2012", "2013"]
    for anio in anios:
        fig = plt.figure()
        fig.set_size_inches(14.3, 9)
        ax = plt.axes()
        plt.hold(True)
        bpArray = []
        i=0
        ticks = []
        for mes in range(len(meses)):
            archivoCO = open(directorioEntrada+"/"+"CO"+"-"+self.mesStr(mes+1)+"-"+anio, encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
            archivoCR = open(directorioEntrada+"/"+"CR"+"-"+self.mesStr(mes+1)+"-"+anio, encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
            datosCOmes = self.obtenerDatosmensuales(archivoCO)
            datosCRmes = self.obtenerDatosmensuales(archivoCR)
            data = [    [int(float(datosCOmes[2])), int(float(datosCOmes[0])), int(float(datosCOmes[1]))],
                        [int(float(datosCRmes[2])), int(float(datosCRmes[0])), int(float(datosCRmes[1]))] ]
            bpArray.append(plt.boxplot(data, positions=[i,i+1], widths=0.5))
            ticks.append(i+0.5)
            i=i+2
        hB, = plt.plot([1,1],'b-')
        hR, = plt.plot([1,1],'r-')
        plt.legend((hB, hR),('Caleta', 'Comodoro'))
        hB.set_visible(False)
        hR.set_visible(False)
        ax.set_xticklabels(meses)
        ax.set_xticks(ticks)
        self.setBoxColors(bpArray)
        plt.title('Variación de temperatura mensual Caleta Olivia-Comodoro Rivadavia. Año '+anio)
        plt.savefig(directorioSalida+"/asdasd"+str(anio)+".ps", orientation='landscape', papertype='A4' )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your boxplot is there but it's hidden. This reproduces your problem:

```
import matplotlib
import numpy as np

data = np.random.normal(10,2,100*24).reshape(24,-1) # let's get 12 pairs of arrays to plot
meses = ["Enero","Febrero","Marzo","Abril","Mayo","Junio", "Julio", "Agosto","Septie.","Octubre","Noviem.","Diciem."]

ax = plt.axes()
plt.hold(True)

i=0

ticks = []

for mes in range(0,len(meses)):
    plt.boxplot(data, positions=[i,i+1], widths=0.5)
    ticks.append(i+0.5)
    i+=2

ax.set_xticklabels(meses)
ax.set_xticks(ticks)    

plt.show()
```

Notice that you are defining your positions as ranging from 0 to 12, but you append `ticks` as `range(0,12) + 0.5`. Thus, when you later do `set_xticks(ticks)`, your x axis will begin from 0.5 but your 1st boxplot is plotted at position 0.

[image: wrong]

I've adapted your code slightly to produce the result you want:

```
ax = plt.axes()
plt.hold(True)

i=1 # we start plotting from position 1 now

ticks = []

for mes in range(0,len(meses)):
    plt.boxplot(data, positions=[i,i+1], widths=0.5)
    ticks.append(i+0.5)
    i+=2

ax.set_xticklabels(meses)
ax.set_xlim(0,ticks[-1]+1) # need to shift the right end of the x limit by 1
ax.set_xticks(ticks)    


plt.show()
```

[image: fixed]